# Find text in one column and then add text to adjacent column MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need a MySQL query to do the following and I am completely stuck.

Find text in one column and then add text to adjacent/other column in a MySQL database.

So I will keep it simple from my columns and text because once I know how the first one works I can adjust from there.

## Column Name 1

Text to find

Then once this text is found I need too add text to the next column.

## Column Name 2

Text to add

Thanks.

Stefan.

Comment: No evidence of any attempt to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET [Column Name 2] = "Text to add"
 WHERE [Column Name 1] like 'Text to find'
```

Comment: Hi Edi, Thank you worked perfectly, i had been looking at it from the wrong angle.